# Java using teradata giving exception - Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata

As per my requirement, I need to pull records from Teradata db. While trying to pull data, I am getting exception as follows.

```
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.09] [Error 3932] [SQLState 25000] Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:307)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:108)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:321)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:202)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:122)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.run(StatementController.java:113)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:380)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:322)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.doNonPrepExecuteQuery(TDStatement.java:310)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeQuery(TDStatement.java:1085)
    at com.uprr.netcontrol.wkfl_mgmt.eventhandler.eventprocessor.TeradataSelectFromVolatileTable.main(TeradataSelectFromVolatileTable.java:26)
```

I think I got this exception because of using Volatile table in my query. But I need to use volatile table as part of query to make grouping on a particular column to get comma separated column data. Please, suggest me how to get result set while using volatile table in query. Here, I am enclosing sample java program to reproduce the exception.

```
package com.sample.package;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TeradataSelectFromVolatileTable {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    String url = "jdbc:teradata://<TERADATA_TABLE_NAME>";
    final String query =
        "CREATE VOLATILE TABLE VT_TEMP AS (" + "SELECT PERS_ID,FIR_NAME FROM          <TABLE_NAME> AS PERSON)"
            + "WITH DATA UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX(PERS_ID) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;" + // volatile table created.
            "SELECT * FROM VT_TEMP;"; // pulling rows.
    Connection con = null;
    try {
      System.out.println(" Looking for the Teradata JDBC driver... ");
      // Loading the Teradata JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
      System.out.println(" JDBC driver loaded. \n");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "<USER_ID>", "<PASSWORD>");
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      System.out.println(" Statement object created. \n");
      ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
//Some operations on resultset goes here...........
      System.out.println(" total column count "  + rset.getMetaData().getColumnCount());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      // Close the statement
      con.close();
      System.out.println("\n Connection object closed. \n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess. Split the SQL into two separate statements and execute them one after another.

Comment: Try setting `TMODE=TERA`  [Clicky!](https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#URL_TMODE).  On a side not, if you're just returning the resultset, why put it in the volatile table at all?

Comment: Andrew, Its just an simple query to reproduce exception. The query that I am working out is joins multiple tables pivoting pers_id column to  group multiple rows data into single column data for other columns. for that, I need volatile table. I hope I cleared your query. BTW, TMODE=TERA, don't work for me.

Comment: KDM, my class is a generic factory pattern class to connect to any type of database(Oracle, mysql, teradata for my case) and runs the query. All other cases, only one query is there. Where as for teradata, I can't slit it into 2 queries.

Comment: Try doing a COMMIT after the creation/loading of the volatile table.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for working on this. Using COMMIT WORK; after create statement doesn't work while running query thru java program. 
`CREATE VOLATILE TABLE VT_TEMP AS 
    (SELECT PERS_ID,FIR_NAME FROM ABCD30.EFG013 AS PERSON) 
    WITH DATA UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX(PERS_ID) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS; 
    
 COMMIT WORK; 
   
SELECT * FROM VT_TEMP;`

Infact, I got Syntax error: COMMIT WORK not allowed for a DBC/SQL session.
 Event I tried with BT;<MY_QUERIES>;ET; also didn't gave luck to me.

Comment: You try to submit both CREATE and SELECT as a multi-statement-request, which is always part of a transaction (or a transaction on it's own), but never allows COMMIT or ET in-between. As any DDL statement must be committed in Teradata before you can use the new table it's impossible to do what you want without splitting it into two separate statements (as KDM already mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to wrap your CT statement in an explicit, Teradata-mode transaction to resolve the error you are receiving:

```
public class TeradataSelectFromVolatileTable {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    String url = "jdbc:teradata://<TERADATA_TABLE_NAME>";
final String query =
        "BT;" + // Begin Teradata-mode Transaction 
        "CREATE VOLATILE TABLE VT_TEMP AS (" + 
              "SELECT PERS_ID,FIR_NAME FROM <TABLE_NAME> AS PERSON)"
            + "WITH DATA UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX(PERS_ID) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;" + // volatile table created. + 
        "ET;" + // End Teradata-mode Transaction
            "SELECT * FROM VT_TEMP;"; // pulling rows.
    Connection con = null;
    try {
      System.out.println(" Looking for the Teradata JDBC driver... ");
      // Loading the Teradata JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
      System.out.println(" JDBC driver loaded. \n");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "<USER_ID>", "<PASSWORD>");
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      System.out.println(" Statement object created. \n");
      ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
//Some operations on resultset goes here...........
      System.out.println(" total column count "  + rset.getMetaData().getColumnCount());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      // Close the statement
      con.close();
      System.out.println("\n Connection object closed. \n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting same exception with your answer though I use with/without teradata mode: jdbc:teradata://<TERADATA_TABLE_NAME>/TMODE=TERA   `com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.09] [Error 3932] [SQLState 25000] Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement`